# Vertex Array Performance Issues

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've been programming OpenGL for some time now but I'm quite new to OpenGL ES. One of issues I'm having is drawing primitives on the screen in an efficient maner.

I need to draw a number of equal line loops on the screen (with different translation) and noticed a huge performance drop with this code:

```
gl.glColor4f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, this.vertices);

for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        gl.glPushMatrix();

        gl.glTranslatef(i, j, 0);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);

        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
}
```

I figure that the *glDrawArrays* is the bad guy here.

So the question is how can I draw a bunch of line loops efficiently? The glDrawArrays must be called for each primitive when using GL_LINE_LOOP so do I need to change the type to GL_LINES? This would impose a huge memory waste since the vertex array (in code above, holding 4 vertices) will then hold **width * height * 8** vertices.

I'm programming for Android OpenGL ES 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figure that the glDrawArrays is the bad guy here.

Yes and no. You are right in saying that DrawArrays is not a fast call, but it is the fastest way of rendering something if you don't call it often.

> so do I need to change the type to GL_LINES?

Yes, so that you can draw everything with one draw call

> This would impose a huge memory waste since the vertex array (in code above, holding 4 vertices) will then hold width * height * 8 vertices.

Compared to just 4 vertices, I guess you could see it as a memoty waste. But GPU's are *built* to render big batches at a time, it will hate you for drawing lot's of little batches.

Also, you should have more than enough memory to hold the vertices, that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I figure that the glDrawArrays is the bad guy here.

The bad guy is you, making such inefficient use of your function calling/context switching budget. Pack all your lines into one array (as GL_LINES) and send it in one single call to the GPU. And no, you're not wasting memory, because you can't allocate less than one page (usually 4kiB) anyway.

Comment: "can't allocate less than one page"? Isn't vertex arrays allocated on the client side?

Comment: @JensÅkerblom: Yes it is. The client side runs Android, which runs on a Linux kernel, which manages memory in pages.